# Application name displayed as Unknown with fbs and PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, fbs

I wrote an application with fbs and PyQt5.
When starting any window, the application name is displayed as *"Unknown"* on Ubuntu 19.04.

[image]

I added the lines:

```
app = AppContext()
app.app.setApplicationName("MyApplication")
app.app.setApplicationDisplayName("MyApplication)
```

The application name is still displayed as "Unknown" like in the picture.
Is there any other way to change the name? And is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

In the base.json of fbs the `app_name` is also set.

```
{
    "app_name": "MyApplication",
    ...
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: You can just start a new project with fbs and you will see that the name is displayed as Unknown.
`pip3 install fbs`
`fbs startproject`
Then type in any application name and finish the setup.
If you then start the application with `fbs run` the application name will be displayed as Unknown on Ubuntu. @eyllanesc

Comment: I've tried it in Arch Linux and it works correctly, I think it's a bug, report it.

Comment: @eyllanesc ok thank you. Is this a fbs or a pyqt bug?

Comment: Create an application without using fbs: `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
app.setApplicationName("MyApplication")
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.show()
app.exec_()`, if the problem persists then it is a bug of PyQt5, but if not then it is only a bug of fbs

Comment: @eyllanesc It's still there, so it's a PyQt Bug. I will write a ticket.

Comment: If you are using the PyQt5 that Ubuntu provides (apt-get) then it is better to report it to Ubuntu, if instead you have used pip then report it to PyQt5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this thread is over a year old, but if you're still running into this problem, I hope this helps. Recently, I also encountered this issue (Python 3.7, PyQt 5.15.0, Ubuntu 18.04), and this is what solved it for me:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from app import MainWindow
import os
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
QtWidgets.qApp.setApplicationName("Some other name here")
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Where MainWindow is a class that extends QMainWindow. It also works if I put  `QtWidgets.qApp.setApplicationName("Some other name here")` in the `__init__` of MainWindow. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: In the `__init__` of `MainWindow`, I set `self.setWindowTitle("Something1"); QtWidgets.qApp.setApplicationName("Something2")`. Yet, when the app runs, the titlebar shows "Unknown" with a dropdown arrow. When I click the dropdown, I see "Unknown" and "Something1" listed. Even when the app is busy, the message shown is that "Unknown is not responding". The string "Something2" is not shown anywhere.